# How to parse XML file in C# using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewSounds>
    <Artists>
      <Artist>Avril Lavigne</Artist>
      <Artist>Bob Marley</Artist>
      <Artist>Coldplay</Artist>
    </Artists>

  <Genres>
    <Genre>Rock</Genre>    
    <Genre>Jazz</Genre>
    <Genre>Metal</Genre>
  </Genres>
</NewSounds>
```

How do I parse this simple XML file in LINQ? I know very little about LINQ, this is what I have:

```
var artists = xml.Descendants("Artists")
                    .Elements("Artist")
                    .Select(a => new Artist {
                        Name = a.Element("Artist").Value
                    }).ToArray();
```

Problem is, it throws up a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error on the `.Select` part (maybe because it can't find the value?).

I'd like to traverse the XML and grab the relevant parts inside the `<Artist>` and `<Genre>` tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` in your `Select()` callback is the `<Artist>` element.  `a.Element("Artist")` isn't anything.

Answer (score 2):

Cast element to string, instead of accessing `Value` property. In this case you will not get exception if element is null:

```
var artists = xml.Descendants("Artists")
                    .Elements("Artist")
                    .Select(a => new Artist {
                        Name = (string)a.Element("Artist")
                    }).ToArray();
```